# How to read files from a virtual machine using python

Tags: python, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm running a virtual machine on my system using Oracle VirtualBox , what i'm trying to accomplish is to read file on  virtual machine from my physical system . i'm using virtualbox api  (pyvbox) to interface with VirtualBox . This the first time i'm using a virtualbox api.

### UPDATE

```
>>> import virtualbox
>>> vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()
>>> vm =vbox.find_machine("XPBox")
>>> session = vm.create_session()
>>> gs = session.console.guest.create_session('xphandler' , ' qwerty')
>>> process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#29>", line 1, in <module>
    process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualbox\library_ext\guest_session.py", line 54, in execute
    process.wait_for(int(library.ProcessWaitResult.start), 0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualbox\library.py", line 13666, in wait_for
    reason = ProcessWaitResult(reason)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\virtualbox\library.py", line 121, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Can not find enumeration where value=%s" % value)
ValueError: Can not find enumeration where value=None
>>>
```

This is the output when i type the below given solution.

Comment: What have you tried? What hasn't worked? You'll need to make sure that the file you are trying to access is visible to the filesystem of your physical machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to copy from a guest VM:
https://gist.github.com/mjdorma/9044686

The traceback you posted seems to happen to a number of users.  It occurs when IProcess.wait_for returns None.  The library attempts to enumerate what type of ProcessWaitResult has been returned.  This happens when vboxapi returns None from an attempted call to the IProcess.wait_for COM interface.

```
 In [5]: virtualbox.library.IProcess.wait_for?
Type:       instancemethod
String Form:<unbound method IProcess.wait_for>
File:       virtualbox\library.py
Definition: virtualbox.library.IProcess.wait_for(self, wait_for, timeout_ms)
Docstring:
Waits for one or more events to happen.

in wait_for of type int
    Specifies what to wait for;
    see <link to="ProcessWaitForFlag"/> for more information.

in timeout_ms of type int
    Timeout (in ms) to wait for the operation to complete.
    Pass 0 for an infinite timeout.

return reason of type ProcessWaitResult
    The overall wait result;
    see <link to="ProcessWaitResult"/> for more information.
```

Tip: Ensure you are running the latest virtualbox release when operating pyvbox.

Answer (score 3):

Read the [pyvbox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyvbox/0.0.4) documentation carefully. I believe you can figure out some solution. The given below example from the doc is not what you want but a good reference to start up.

```
ipython

In [1]: import virtualbox

In [2]: vbox = virtualbox.VirtualBox()

In [3]: vm = vbox.find_machine('test_vm')

In [4]: session = vm.create_session()

In [5]: gs = session.console.guest.create_session('Name', 'password')

In [6]: process, stdout, stderr = gs.execute('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe', ['/C', 'tasklist'])

In [7]: print stdout
```

Comment: Yeah i tried this code . But it gave me an Error, iv'e pasted the response above.

Comment: The error is coming from the constructor of Enum class. Where the value is none. Now it's quite tough to tell what is happening at your side. So have a look at the library.py and try to debug why the value is none. 

https://github.com/mjdorma/pyvbox/blob/master/virtualbox/library.py

Also instead of line 6 try the Example "Write text into a window on a running machine:" from the pyvbox link. 

Let me know your findings. Monday I can have a setup and can dig the issue.

Comment: Ok ,will do. will try from my end too.